# Does a non-fractional Racial Favored Class Bonus stack with itself?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-levels

This question is similar to [this](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/69851/favored-class-bonus-scaling-overpowered) one, but the difference in this case is about non-fractional Racial Alternate Favored Class Bonuses and if they stack.

Take a look at the Dwarf Alternate Favored Class Bonuses for a [Wizard](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/#TOC-Favored-Class-Bonuses).

> Select one item creation feat known by the wizard. Whenever crafting an item using that feat, the amount of progress made in an 8-hour period increases by 200 gp (50 gp if crafting while adventuring). This does not reduce the cost of the item; it just increases the rate at which the item is crafted.

Could our level 5 Dwarven Wizard, Rodney, take this Alternate Favored Class Bonus 3 times for Craft Wondrous to be able to craft 1600 gp of Wondrous items per day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Since the ability description does not mention that it can only be taken once or a limited amount of times. The class bonuses are meant to be taken every level, so it does not make sense for there to be one that can only be taken once. If an ability is too good, they put a caps on it as we see in other cases.